# In Class methods, why does one method seem to accept instance variables and another doesn't?

Tags: ruby

In the following code example, why does the second (sheetplus) method seem to pick up the instance variables @name and @occupation fine, but the first (sheet) method return nil?  I feel like I'm missing something deadly obvious, but I am basically the world's worst Ruby programmer.

```
class Test
def initialize(name, occupation)
  @name = name
  @occupation = occupation
def sheet
  "This is #@name, who is a/an #@occupation"
def sheetplus
  "This is #@name, who is a/an #@occupation, but why does this method succeed where the previous one fails?"
end
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the code directly pasted in, you aren't closing your initialize or sheet method definitions.

```
class Test
  def initialize(name, occupation)
    @name = name
    @occupation = occupation
  end
  def sheet
   "This is #@name, who is a/an #@occupation"
  end
  def sheetplus
    "This is #@name, who is a/an #@occupation, but why does this method succeed where the previous one fails?"
  end
end
```

Who knows what could happen at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Did you really mean to nest all those definitions? Perhaps you meant:

```
class Test
  def initialize(name, occupation)
    @name = name
    @occupation = occupation
  end

  def sheet
    "This is #{@name}, who is a/an #{@occupation}"
  end

  def sheetplus
    "This is #{@name}, who is a/an #{@occupation}, but why does this method succeed where the previous one fails?"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Other people have already explained what your problem is, namely putting your `ends` in the wrong place, however if you are interested in knowing why you are getting the results you are getting then this is why.

`t = Test.new('Joe', 'Farmer')`

This creates a new instance of your Test Class.  The initializer has defined a new method called `sheet` that does nothing but define a method called `sheetplus`

If you now call `sheetplus` then you will get an error as the `sheetplus` method does not exist yet (`sheet` has not been run to create it)

```
t.sheetplus
NoMethodError: undefined method `sheetplus' for 
  #<Test:0x11a9dec @name="Joe", @occupation="Farmer">
    from (irb):14
```

If you now call `sheet` it will define the `sheetplus` method and will return the result of defining the method (nil)

```
t.sheet # nil
```

If you now call sheetplus the method exists so it succeeds

```
t.sheetplus
=> "This is Joe, who is a/an Farmer, but why does this method succeed 
   where the previous one fails?"
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  It's good to know the *reason* behind the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Because your keywords are in the wrong place. This will work as you expect it to:

```
class Test
  def initialize(name, occupation)
    @name = name
    @occupation = occupation
  end
  def sheet
    "This is #@name, who is a/an #@occupation"
  end
  def sheetplus
    "This is #@name, who is a/an #@occupation, but why does this method succeed where the previous one fails?"
  end
end
```